# FileZilla sftp attempts to authorize via key before set password

Tags: ssh, sftp, filezilla, ssh-keys

I'm using FileZilla to sftp into a remote server. The logon type is "normal" with a username and password set. However, when I try to connect, based on level 3 debugging in FileZilla, it tries all of my ssh keys  BEFORE trying the password. Once it hits the 6th ssh key, it rejects me with the error:

```
Error:          type 2 (protocol error):
Error:          "Too many authentication failures for root"
```

The issue is that the login method is set to normal, not key file. Why is FileZilla trying to authenticate via my ssh keys and not the credentials I provided? My current workaround is to remove my ssh keys on my local machine so that FileZilla tries (and fails) only the 4 keys I have locally, and once that fails, it then tries the username + password and successfully logs me in.

Comment: I have the exact same issue. On the command line, I was able to avoid this problem by creating an entry for the server in my SSH config with `PreferredAuthentications password` and `PubkeyAuthentication no` but I don't know how to make FileZilla do the same.